# WHat's the best way to take a first defined value from a stream and unsubscribe in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have the following code:

```
this.type$.pipe(
        filter(val => !!val), // skip initial undefined value
        take(1), // unsubscribe after geting the first defined value
        map((type) => {
          this.store.dispatch(new LoadForms(type.schemaUid));
        })
      ).subscribe();
```

This is the pattern I use in few places across my app. Is there a way to shorten that by using any smarter RxJS operator? It should take just the value that is defined and immediately unsubscribe then.

Comment: You mean shorter way than `take(1)`?

Comment: I mean filtering ```undefined``` values, just taking first defined data and end subscription.

Comment: Use `first(Boolean)`. This will also filter out `null` and `false` if that's ok with you.

Comment: That's a good solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `single()`

```
this.type$.pipe(
        filter(val => !!val), 
        single()
```

or with a filter function

```
this.type$.pipe(
        first(val => !!val),...
```